# cURL php get url of all images

Tags: php

I get this error by using the following code any suggestion why this error occur and how to solve..

> Notice: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Namespace prefix g is not defined in
>   Entity, line: 74 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\img.php on line 43
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag g:plusone invalid in Entity,
>   line: 74 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\img.php on line 43
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in
>   Entity, line: 82 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\img.php on line 43
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in
>   Entity, line: 82 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\img.php on line 43
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): End tag : expected '>' in Entity,
>   line: 104 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\img.php on line 43
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : g in Entity,
>   line: 104 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\img.php on line 43
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : head in Entity,
>   line: 149 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\img.php on line 43
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced 
>   tag in Entity, line: 150 in C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\img.php on line 43

**My code so far:**

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
                $dom = new domDocument;
                $dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$html);
                $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
                foreach($images as $image){
                    $img = $image->getAttribute('src');
                    echo $img."</br>";
                }
```

Comment: Your HTML is probably malformed?

Comment: i get the images urls of any webpage but error occur as i mention in my question . it also give me the urls but with error .

Comment: Well, show us that documents content, how else are we meant to help?

Comment: #arkascha  will u plz execute this code in your . give any url in first line .

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes in your code:

1. The first one is the concatenation of `<?xml encoding="UTF-8">` with the html. Juste delete it
2. The second one is you don't use [`libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) to disable libxml errors

So here's the code that work for me:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://culturevie.info/tag-d.html?s=france");
$dom = new domDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors (true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($images as $image){
        $img = $image->getAttribute('src');
        echo $img."</br>";
}
```